# DataFrame string exact match

Tags: python, pandas, string, numpy, find

I am using the `str.contains` method to look for a specific row in a data frame. I however want to find an exact string match, and even if I add `regex = False`, it seems to pick up the partial matches.

`str.find` doesn't work either, is there another function I should be using for this? Here is a snippet where I need it in:

Here is some code for replication

```
data = {'A':['tree','bush','forest','tree/red']}

df_test=pd.DataFrame(data)

df_test['New'] = np.where(df_test['A'].str.contains('tree', regex = False) |
                                   df_test['A'].str.contains('bush') |
                                   df_test['A'].str.contains('forest') 
    
                                   , 'Good', '')
```

So I would like to code above to only find rows with 'tree','bush' or 'forest', however it also picks up rows which say 'tree/red'.

[image]

Comment: Use `df_test.A.isin` for exact matching.  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html

Comment: `df_test['A'].str.fullmatch('tree')` use `.str.fullmatch` not `.str.contains`

Comment: You can enable `regex` and simply put "^" at the beginning and "$" at the end of your pattern so that you specify the boundary. For example, `.str.contains('^tree$')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str.contains` checks if the substring exists in the string so either you use a complicated regex to get the required output or you can simple find another way.

here is how i would do it

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {'A':['tree','bush','forest','tree/red']}
good = ['tree','bush','forest',]
df_test=pd.DataFrame(data)
df_test['New'] = df_test.apply(lambda row: 'Good' if row['A'] in good else 'Bad', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str.contains` with `^` and `$` markers:

```py
df_test['New'] = np.where(df_test['A'].str.contains('^(?:tree|bush|forest)$', regex=True), 'Good', '')
```

Note also here that we are using a single regex pattern with an alternation to search for all keywords at the same time.